# Ruby unpack binary to arbitrary bits

Tags: ruby, binary-data, unpack

There is an unpack method to build a representation of a binary string as an array of integers, strings, etc, but I cannot find a way to split on arbitrary bits (for example 11 b**i**ts).

[Ruby unpack binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125275/ruby-unpack-binary) solves the problem for arbitrary bytes length strings, but it does not work for bits.

I would like to implement something like this:

```rb
'binarydata'
  .unpack('b11b11b11b11b11') # => ["01000110100", ... ]     
  .map { |b| b.to_i(2) }     # => [564, 948, 628, 308, 372]
  .pack('magic')             # => 'binarydata'
```

The problem is that it is not readable and build strings (that does not look performant). Also, the unpack part requires knowing the size (because `'b11*'` is not a valid template string.